# Minimum value returning 0 on an array (goal is to find max and min)

Tags: arrays, max, min, subscript

Thanks in advance. I'm having trouble figuring out why my code is giving me trouble when I print a minimum value for this array. It seems to be retaining the initial 0 value for min, but I'm not sure how to correct this. Max works fine. Did I set the max and min values in the wrong part of the program?

Also, this is my first assignment with arrays so I might have some questions about printing subscripts later on.

Thanks again!

EDIT- this fixed the problem, to my knowledge. Thanks Dan W.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a new number. This will continue until "
                + "you reach the size of the array. ");
        arrayOfNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
            int max = arrayOfNumbers[0];
            int min = arrayOfNumbers[0];
```

---

```
package program8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS;
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of numbers the array will read in. ");
        NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = keyboard.nextInt();
                int arrayOfNumbers[] = new int[NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS];
                int max = arrayOfNumbers[0];
                int min = arrayOfNumbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a new number. This will continue until "
                    + "you reach the size of the array. ");
            arrayOfNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (max <= arrayOfNumbers[i])
                max = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (min >= arrayOfNumbers[i])
                min = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        }
                System.out.print(+max+ "max and " +min+ " min");
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What values are you inputting? Because an `int` has a default value of 0: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
So, if you're only inputting positive numbers, the min will always be 0.

To avoid this, initialize min and max after you have the user input the numbers, that way the max and min are not defaulted to 0.

Comment: Like the above? (i don't know how to place code in comments without it looking terrible so it's in the edit, above the original. I got it working this way. I've tried this before but it didn't work because I had it within the brackets of the first for loop. Thanks! Does that look right?

Comment: And yes, I was only inputting positive numbers at the time. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that looks right. Hope it works. Please accept the answer if this fixed your problem.

Comment: I would but I'm not really sure what you mean- I clicked yes when it asks if the post is useful, but I don't have the reputation to upvote you. Is there something else I'm supposed to do? nevermind! found it. thanks!